# "Hide" a YouTube Video's Loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

After looking through the [YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), I haven't been able to find anything that can help me.

My goal is to "hide" the loading screen a YouTube video has; i.e. this black screen with a spinning wheel. While it only appears for a brief second and doesn't bother me, it's bothersome when trying to use a YouTube as the background of an element.

[image: YouTube video loading]

My approach to solving this problem was to have a picture of the first frame of the YouTube video overlap the video and then hide it when video starts playing. I originally thought I'd be able to use `onStateChange` and watch for the `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING` value so I can hide the image but this event is triggered when it is about to start playing; in other words, it hides the images when the video is about to start playing which is when the loading screen appears.

Are there any other approaches to this or am I stuck with the brief loading screen or would a self-hosted video be the better approach? I wanted to avoid self-hosting the video because of bandwidth.

Comment: The biggest hurdle is the iframe. You essentially can not touch anything inside the iframe. The only outside the box idea I could come up with would be to watch for the color of a pixel to change from black. You'll still be running into issues with reading any value inside the iframe.

Comment: Can't you listen to [`onStateChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) when the video is cued (hence ready to play)? Before that you can hide the video, or obscure it by overlaying it with a blank element (or a still from the video), and then remove the overlay when video is cued.

Comment: @Terry, my bad, I made a typo. I am listening to the onStateChange event. If I understand correctly, the cue status only applies for playlists and such since it's not being shown in the onStateChange event.

Comment: @allejo You able to achieve this? Please let me know if Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host the video and use an API where you can; customize the media player, hide / show / customize load screens, **cue points**, **start poster / end poster**, etc. Or else your spending your time hacking youtube API capabilities with funky javascript.

JW player: http://www.jwplayer.com/

Flow Player: https://flowplayer.org/docs/cuepoints.html

And many others you could check out.

*video.js, popcorn.js*, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

set the background of the iframe container to black and set the iframe opacity to 0, once it starts playing set the opacity back to 1

Comment: awesome.  I threw a css transition on here and it looks awesome.

Comment: how you did this.. how you detect is iframe start playing?

Comment: the youtube player fire events, you can see more details here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="player" style="background: #FFFFFF; opacity: 0;"></div>

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
```

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
   //    The function indicates that when playing a video(state=1),
   //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.

```
if (event.data === 1) {
    console.log('video plays');
    document.getElementById("player").style.opacity = "1";
}
```