# javascript to hide the black loading screen of a youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, loading

I need to hide the video background of my website until the video has loaded to avoid the black loading screen. I cannot modify the HTML and I have to load the video through youtube. I'd like to use onlaodedata and CSS display:none;  But I cannot get the right script.

The youtube video player is inside an iframe and the iframe is inside a div `class="jqbga-web--video"`.
The CSS `display:none;` only works with the div `.jqbga-web--video` not with the iframe id `#jdbga-youtube-video-player_1477846903212`

so I guess I need `document.getElementsByClassName("jqbga-web--video");`

Can you give me the right script?

Comment: what do you want to be there instead of a black screen?

Comment: misread your question. this might be what you're looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755250/hide-a-youtube-videos-loading-screen/29756070